# Adding ImageBackground to React Native Login Screen

Tags: react-native

I found this great code sample/layout -- see below -- for a React Native login screen. All I want to do is to have an `ImageBackground` as opposed to the current solid background.

When I add `ImageBackground` to the code, it throws everything off and instead of the image covering the entire screen, everything gets squished in the middle and all alingment gets out of whack. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the original code with solid background:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state={
    email:"",
    password:""
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.logo}>HeyAPP</Text>
        <View style={styles.inputView} >
          <TextInput  
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder="Email..." 
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({email:text})}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView} >
          <TextInput  
            secureTextEntry
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder="Password..." 
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({password:text})}/>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.forgot}>Forgot Password?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Signup</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

  
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#003f5c',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  logo:{
    fontWeight:"bold",
    fontSize:50,
    color:"#fb5b5a",
    marginBottom:40
  },
  inputView:{
    width:"80%",
    backgroundColor:"#465881",
    borderRadius:25,
    height:50,
    marginBottom:20,
    justifyContent:"center",
    padding:20
  },
  inputText:{
    height:50,
    color:"white"
  },
  forgot:{
    color:"white",
    fontSize:11
  },
  loginBtn:{
    width:"80%",
    backgroundColor:"#fb5b5a",
    borderRadius:25,
    height:50,
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center",
    marginTop:40,
    marginBottom:10
  },
  loginText:{
    color:"white"
  }
});
```

This produces this nice layout:

[image]

And I simply add an image background with the following code which doesn't work at all:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <ImageBackground
           source={require("../../assets/images/background/teton_snake_dimmed.jpg")}
           style={styles.imageBackground}
    >
       <Text style={styles.logo}>HeyAPP</Text>
          <View style={styles.inputView} >
              <TextInput
                  style={styles.inputText}
                  placeholder="Email..."
                  placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
                  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ email: text })} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputView}>
              <TextInput
                  secureTextEntry
                  style={styles.inputText}
                  placeholder="Password..."
                  placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
                  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })} />
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity>
               <Text style={styles.forgot}>Forgot Password?</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn}>
               <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOGIN</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity>
               <Text style={styles.loginText}>Signup</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    </ImageBackground>
</View>
```

And here's the updated styles. The only thing I add is the `imageBackground`:

```
   container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#003f5c',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
   },
   logo: {
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 50,
      color: "#fb5b5a",
      marginBottom: 40
   },
   imageBackground: {
      flex: 1,
      resizeMode: "cover"
   },
   inputView: {
      width: "80%",
      backgroundColor: "#465881",
      borderRadius: 25,
      height: 50,
      marginBottom: 20,
      justifyContent: "center",
      padding: 20
   },
   inputText: {
      backgroundColor: "#465881",
      height: 50,
      color: "white"
   },
   forgot: {
      color: "white",
      fontSize: 11
   },
   loginBtn: {
      width: "80%",
      backgroundColor: "#fb5b5a",
      borderRadius: 25,
      height: 50,
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      marginTop: 40,
      marginBottom: 10
   },
   loginText: {
      color: "white"
   }
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. Here's the original code published by @Alhydra:
https://github.com/Alhydra/React-Native-Login-Screen-Tutorial/blob/master/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example replace the image with the image you want

snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/intelligent-banana

code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://media.gettyimages.com/videos/loopable-color-gradient-background-animation-video-id1182636595?s=640x640',
          }}
        />
        <View style={styles.subContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.logo}>HeyAPP</Text>
          <View style={styles.inputView}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputText}
              placeholder="Email..."
              placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ email: text })}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputView}>
            <TextInput
              secureTextEntry
              style={styles.inputText}
              placeholder="Password..."
              placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ password: text })}
            />
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.forgot}>Forgot Password?</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn}>
            <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOGIN</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.loginText}>Signup</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#003f5c',
  },
  subContainer: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 50,
    color: '#fb5b5a',
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  inputView: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: '#465881',
    borderRadius: 25,
    height: 50,
    marginBottom: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  inputText: {
    height: 50,
    color: 'white',
  },
  forgot: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 11,
  },
  loginBtn: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: '#fb5b5a',
    borderRadius: 25,
    height: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  loginText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

Comment: You're not using `ImageBackground` and looks like setting an image size. Will this work correctly on all devices -- including tablets such as iPad, Galaxy, etc.? I thought using `ImageBackground` would be more robust.